# How to append/link Screens from other blendfiles?

Tags: python, interface

Is there a way to append/link a screen (see below) from a different blend file?

If not possible from the UI maybe this can be done via python?

I would like to create a custom screen and then deliver this via an addon. Once the addon is loaded it should append its screen to the opened blendfile if possible.

---

Clarification by @Pistache

A Blender "Screen" is a specific type of data-block ([see Blender's documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/data_blocks.html)), however it is not available when using `bpy.data.libraries.load` (`data_in` has no attribute `screen`/`screens`), or even using the `append` operator (it does not show up in the list of appendable objects in the GUI).

Comment: As a possible starting point.  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38060/how-to-link-append-with-a-python-script

Comment: ndee and @pistache I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "screen". Can you please elaborate or add an example?

Answer (score 4):

A screen layout created in one .blend file cannot be linked/appended (manually or with python) into another, because Blender [does not support this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/data_blocks.html#data-block-types).

With python you can create new screen layout (`bpy.ops.screens.new()`) and [change it's areas](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=python%20area) how ever you like.

You can access data inside external .blend files and read them with [Blender-file](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blender-file).

This can be turned into addon for ease of use.